# JavaFX 8: Checkbox in TableView and Add-on into to selected Item?

Tags: checkbox, tableview, javafx-8, insert-update

I would like to create a payroll program such that when the user tick a CheckBox in TableView, the name (String) will be carried on to the panel on the right and with TextFields to enter more info such as this:

[image: this]

I tried to follow the MVC hierarchy thus far as I code:

**PayrollMainApp.java**

```
public class PayrollMainApp extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;

    private ObservableList<Employee> selectEmployeeTable = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    
    
    public PayrollMainApp(){
        selectEmployeeTable.add(new Employee(false,"Hans Muster"));
        selectEmployeeTable.add(new Employee(true,"Ruth Mueller"));
        selectEmployeeTable.add(new Employee(false,"Heinz Kurz"));
        selectEmployeeTable.add(new Employee(false,"Cornelia Meier"));
        selectEmployeeTable.add(new Employee(false,"Werner Meyer"));
        selectEmployeeTable.add(new Employee(false,"Lydia Kunz"));
        selectEmployeeTable.add(new Employee(false,"Anna Best"));
        selectEmployeeTable.add(new Employee(false,"Stefan Meier"));
        selectEmployeeTable.add(new Employee(false,"Martin Mueller"));
    }

    public ObservableList<Employee> getSelectEmployeeTable(){
        return selectEmployeeTable;
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("PayrollApp");

        initRootLayout();

        showEmployeeOverview();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the root layout.
     */
    public void initRootLayout() {
        try {
            // Load root layout from fxml file.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(PayrollMainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

            // Show the scene containing the root layout.
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows the person overview inside the root layout.
     */
    public void showEmployeeOverview() {
        try {
            // Load person overview.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(PayrollMainApp.class.getResource("view/EmployeeOverview.fxml"));
            AnchorPane personOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            // Set person overview into the center of root layout.
            rootLayout.setCenter(personOverview);

            // Give the controller access to the main app
            EmployeeOverviewController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainApp(this);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the main stage.
     * @return
     */
    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Employee.java**

```
    public class Employee {

        private BooleanProperty checkedBox = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        private StringProperty employeeName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        
        public Employee(){
            super();
        }
        public Employee(boolean checkedBox, String employeeName){
            this.checkedBox = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
            this.employeeName = new SimpleStringProperty(employeeName);
        }
        public BooleanProperty checkedBoxProperty(){
            return this.checkedBox;
        }
        public StringProperty employeeNameProperty(){
            return this.employeeName;
        }
    
        public java.lang.Boolean getSelectBox() {
            return this.checkedBoxProperty().get();
        }
    
        public StringProperty getEmployeeName() {
            return employeeName;
        }
        public void setSelectBox(final java.lang.Boolean checkedBox){
            this.checkedBoxProperty().set(checkedBox);
        }
        public void setEmployeeName(StringProperty employeeName) {
            this.employeeName = employeeName;
        }
    }
```

**EmployeeOverviewController.java**

```
public class EmployeeOverviewController {    
        @FXML
        private TableView<Employee> selectEmployeeTable;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Employee, String> employeeNameColumn;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<Employee, Boolean> checkBoxColumn;
    
        private PayrollMainApp mainApp;
    
        public EmployeeOverviewController() {
        }
    
        @FXML
        public void initialize() {
            checkBoxColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().checkedBoxProperty());
            checkBoxColumn.setCellFactory(param -> new CheckBoxTableCell<Employee, Boolean>());
            employeeNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().employeeNameProperty());
        }
    
    
        public void setMainApp(PayrollMainApp mainApp){
            this.mainApp = mainApp;
    
            //Add observable list data to the table
            selectEmployeeTable.setItems(mainApp.getSelectEmployeeTable());
        }
    }
```

And a util class to make the checkBox visible in the table:

**SelectBoxCellFactory.java**

```
public class SelectBoxCellFactory implements Callback {
    @Override
    public TableCell call(Object param) {
        CheckBoxTableCell<Employee,Boolean> checkBoxCell = new CheckBoxTableCell();
        return checkBoxCell;
    }
}
```

Here is my output thus far:

[image: here]

I know this has a table in it as compared to the previous output. Honestly I'm still indecisive as to use which, because I think using TextFields would make it look better. But all I hope for now is that this design is not impossible to code...

I really hope you can help me... Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to use a `TableView` for the right panel. You can create a [`FilteredList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html) from your original list:

```
FilteredList<Employee> selectedEmployees 
    = new FilteredList<>(selectEmployeeTable, Employee::getSelectBox);
```

and then use that for your second table.

If you prefer to use text fields (in what looks like a `GridPane`?) you can still use the filtered list above, but you will need to register a listener with it and update the layout "by hand" when items are added and removed.